# Carbon Blade Aced - 20% more effective?

Tags: payday-2

What does it mean by 20% more effective? The saw lasts 20% longer before needing to change the blade? The upgrade before it says it makes it 20% more efficient.

Does 20% more effective mean the same thing as efficient? Or does effective mean 20% more damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it does more damage. If it normally did 100 points of damage, the upgrade would allow it to do 120 points of damage.